# Use fread efficiently to read sparse data

Tags: c, file

I have a file that stores the data like the following

```
A1 B1 C1 ...  A2 B2 C2 ...  .... An Bn Cn ...
```

Here Ai, Bi, and Ci are blocks with 16 bytes. Each chunk Ai Bi Ci ... could be >1M large, and n could be 256. I wanted to read A1, A2... An in sequence, then B1, B2 ... Bn in sequence...

If I am using fread A1, fseek to A2, fread A2, ..., I guess it wastes a lot of IO bandwidth. fread could read 4k bytes from disk at each call, after I do fseek, the cached data by the last fread could be lost. After reading all As, reading B1 needs to read from disk directly but not cache.

Is this assumption correct? I am not sure if file systems can be smart and still keep the cache with B1. If file systems do not help this case, I may have to implement myfread its a wrapper of fread but caches the 256 * 4k data in my own buffer, so the next round of reading Bs can be faster. myfread reads from the buffer until it reaches out of 4k, then it needs fread the real data. But I know fread is not a simple API, can myfread be a simple implementation? Do I need to consider any consistency of file systems? In my case I know no one writes the files when I read.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the file system, it's the hdd/ssd will also cache. Also Linux will use any spare RAM to cache as much of the file system as it can, throwing it away only as programs allocate memory (I don't know how I make its selection as to what to cache).

Most things will cache blocks, and replace un-used data with data that either is being used by a program, or is close by to used data. Your sparse access is going to be hard work for a cache.

Two options to consider - either 1) read the whole file into a single block of data and do the subdividing later (256MB of data in RAM is nothing these days, just look at Web browser memory consumption, they really are memory hogs), or 2) set up a RAM drive and copy the file to it before using it.

2) is easier, nothing will be quicker then 1)